# Problem to redirect using htaccess with two parameter in url in php

Tags: .htaccess, url

How to redirect from these URL using `.htaccess`.

I have a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/try1/1/php
```

When I click on `contact.php` page on the menu my URL change to

```
http://localhost/try1/1/contact.php
```

I want like this

```
http://localhost/try1/contact.php
```

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ video_about.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want to redirect from/to - it's not clear from your question? What's `/try1/1/php`? Is `conatact` just a typo in your question? What code do you currently have in `.htaccess`?

Comment: i have these htaccess code RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ video_about.php?id=$1&title=$2 problem is that when i have url https://localhost/try1/id/title in url and i click on my menu conatact it dont redirect the path changes to http://localhost/try1/1/contact.php i want to change http://localhost/try1/contact.php using htaccess

Comment: "i click on my menu conatact it dont redirect the path changes to" - It sounds like you are linking to the wrong URL? (Since there's nothing in your `.htaccess` that perform a "redirect".) If you want the URL to _look_ a certain way then you need to actually link to that URL - this is not something you necessarily "fix" in `.htaccess`, if that is what you are trying to do?